# Remove eventhandler dynamically from a control, from another module/class Visual Basic .NET 2010

Tags: vb.net, event-handling

I have a function defined in a module which updates the passed byref Combobox and Listbox controls.

for simplicity, say that the definition is as under

```
Module isDB
  private sub PopulateCBO(byref CBO as combobox)
      'Here I want to remove SelectedValueChanged and click events temporarily removed using
      'removehandler or eventhandler.remove 
  End Sub
End Module
```

The control maybe on any form from the project.

Comment: This is possible, but don't do that. Instead, have a method in the Form's class that is responsible for unsubscribing to the event and call _that method_ from the module. Even better, move the `PopulateCBO` method altogether to the form and call it from the module.

Comment: There is most likely no justification for declaring that parameter `ByRef`. For a reference type, which controls are, the ONLY reason to declare a parameter `ByRef` is if you want to assign an object to the parameter inside the method and have the original reference reflect that change. If you're passing a control in to be configured then you're not doing that so there's no reason to declare the parameter `ByRef`.

Comment: Why are you removing the event handlers?  You've written "temporarily", which implies you're wiring them back up.  Why not just declare a boolean variable that you can toggle so that all handlers can stay in place?  A simple check of the boolean in the handler will allow you to exit without doing anything...

Answer (score 0):

To remove an event handler you need a reference to an object that raises an event and a delegate for a method that handles that event. You can't arbitrarily clear all handlers for an event. As such, you cannot remove event handlers in the method you've shown. You'd have to pass the event handler in as well, e.g.

```vb
Public Sub ConfigureComboBox(comboBox As ComboBox, onSelectedIndexChanged As EventHandler)
    '...

    RemoveHandler comboBox.SelectedIndexChanged, onSelectedIndexChanged
End Sub
```

You would then call that in a form like so:

```vb
ConfigureComboBox(ComboBox1, AddressOf ComboBoxes_SelectedIndexChanged)
```

Answer (score 0):

My around turned out to be fairly simple.

I disabled the comboboox with enabled = false and then in the event handler function, I checked if it is enabled =false

Although removing and adding handlers with all their pros and cons didn't even function :)

What I mean is apart of from alternatives, I still wonder who to do that?
The solutions above did not work on my vb 2010.

```
Private Sub cboProgram_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cboProgram.SelectedIndexChanged
    If cboProgram.Enabled = True Then
        MsgBox("Enabled, so the real event handler")
    Else
        MsgBox("Disabled, so a false positive")
    End If
End Sub
```